# FoxToPhone or Chrome2Phone for iPhone

Tags: iphone, applications

Is there a FoxToPhone or Chrome2Phone app for the iPhone?

Chrome2Phone is an app for Android OS, and goes hand in hand with a Chrome or Firefox extension.

Basically lets you send the url of the web page you are surfing to your phone, or some text on the web page. Very useful. Easier than emailing it to yourself.

But I haven't found equivalent for the iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the app store and I found a few apps that can sync with Firefox and some other browsers.  Below are some details.

**i-Pusher ($2.99, no ratings):** Submit various content from your favorite desktop browser into your i-Device in one click...you will instantly receive a link, text, image or youtube video link on your mobile device. Personal Note: You do have to install the appropriate extension in your desktop browser.

**Firefox Home (Free, 3/5 stars)** Firefox Home Provides access to your desktop history, bookmarks and open tabs on your iPhone.  Personal Note: Not a web browser itself.  I think this is close to home of what you need.  I played with this before and I was able to continue browsing my opened tabs on my desktop Firefox using its Firefox Sync feature. http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/firefox-home/id380366933?mt=8

**360 Web Browser | Download Manager and Firefox Sync (99¢, 4/5 stars)** Personal Note: This is actually a third party browser with many desktop like functionality like add ons and download managers with many configuration settings. It uses Firefox Sync, found in Settings in the app.  I just reread its description and apparently it can also do Flash Videos using a CC Plugin. http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/360-web-browser-download-manager/id387737097?mt=8

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I'll take a look at those. i-Pusher looks like what I'm after. Strangely it doesn't seem that popular yet. A bit pricey, they would do better at 1.99 or .99.

Comment: I wonder though if i-Pusher is safe. Not to be biased, but it looks like its from Russia, and I identify Russian software with Hackers. It may not be based in reality, but its just how I feel.